# Publishing a Gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, gmail-addons

When trying to publish my Gmail addon I get this error from the Chrome web store:

> API Console project with the id specified in the manifest's
>   api_console_project_id field, does not have Google Apps Marketplace
>   SDK enabled.

I've enabled the Marketplace SDK, and in its configuration when I'm adding the 'Gmail extension deployment ID" I get this error:

> "Deployment Id is not associated with current project."

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mistake was to go to the Chrome Web Store.
Publishing is done by pressing the red 'Create' button here:

```
Publish -> Deploy from manifest -> Create
```